# QR Code with SpraedPDFGenerator

Tags: symfony, pdf

I'm using SpraedPDFGenerator to generate PDF files from a Twig template. I'm tryign to add a QR Code to my template. I did manage to do that but the QR only appears if I render the Twig for testing but when I generate the PDF using the bundle it doesn't appear.
This is what is recommended for images using this bundle:

```
<img src="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('img/test.jpg') }}"></img>
```

In the bundle they precised that you should only use absolute paths for images but I can't do that because I'm generating the image:

```
<img src="{{ qrcode_url('message', extension='png') }}" />
```

Comment: What is this qrcode_url function? Did you create it?

Comment: I'm using this bundle. [endroid](https://github.com/endroid/EndroidQrCodeBundle)

Comment: This is weird, I looked at the source code for that bundle and it is generating an absolute URL. They use this code `return $this->container->get('router')->generate('endroid_qrcode', $params, true);` Notice the last true param, this is telling Symfony to generate an absolute URL. What do you get?

Comment: Also, you could perhaps try the `qrcode_data_uri` option of that bundle. Perhaps the PDF generator can handle that type of data

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it to work with:  `<img src="{{ asset(qrcode_url('test' , extension='png'),null,true) }}" /></img>` and I honestly don't know why.

Comment: @CarlosGranados if you have an explanation I will put an answer.